# C: Attempting to declare a variable results in an undeclared variable error

Tags: c, variable-declaration, undeclared-identifier

I was just working on a little programming project, and I got a fairly common error about something being undeclared:

```
MP_HighLevelData.c:230:15: error: ‘RemovedUser’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Thinking I had just forgotten to declare the variable, I went along to the line in my source file, and found that the error was pointing at this line of code:

```
User *RemovedUser;
```

Odd, I can't declare a new variable because it doesn't exist? I'm sure it's not specifically this line of code that's at fault, so here's a more complete code snippet. I'd really like to know what I've done wrong.

```
void RemoveUserFromGameRoom(User *User) {

  if (User->GameRoom != NULL) {
    GameRoom *GameRoom = User->GameRoom;

    if (GameRoom->Owner == User) {

      // We should delete the whole game room, since the owner is leaving and a new owner isn't chosen automatically
      while (GameRoom->UsersHead != NULL) { // Awesome way of looping while there are users left in the room
        // We need to get rid of all the users in this game room, including the owner, before we can remove it
        User *RemovedUser;
        RemovedUser = GameRoom->UsersHead->User;
        DeleteUserPtrFromGameRoom(GameRoom->UsersHead); // Remove reference to the user from the game room
        RemovedUser->GameRoom = NULL; // Remove reference to the game room from the user (needs to be set afterwards, whoops)
      }

      // All the users have been kicked out, now we can take care of the game room
      FreeRIDfromGameCategory(GameRoom->RID, User->GameCategory);
      ClearGameRoomName(GameRoom);
      DeleteGameRoomFromGameCategory(GameRoom, User->GameCategory);

    } else {
      UserPtr *UserPtr = GameRoom->UsersHead;

      while (UserPtr != NULL) {
        if (UserPtr->User == User) {
          DeleteUserPtrFromGameRoom(UserPtr);
          User->GameRoom = NULL;
          break;
        }

        UserPtr = UserPtr->next;
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: (User *User) - are you sure compiler can distinguish between the User type and User parameter?

Comment: @AlexFarber hmm. missed it. the error must be that `user is not a type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when faced with the decision of 'Type' or 'Variable of type', the compile will always assume 'Variable of type', which is why accessing `User` as object works.

However, at the same time, declaring a new object with the type `User` fails to work, because for the compiler, that's a variable, not a type.

In short: Rename your variable `User` to anything but the type name (i.e. `UserObject` or something), and your code should work just fine in that regard.

For the clarification, this is my suggested fix:

```
void RemoveUserFromGameRoom(User *myUser) {

    if (myUser->GameRoom != NULL) {
        GameRoom *GameRoom = myUser->GameRoom;
        //More code to come
    }
    //Some more code
 }
```

Comment: The funny thing is, I have User *RemovedUser; in another function in the same source file, and it doesn't generate an error. And it comes before this function...

Comment: @WillWill56 Yeah, because THAT isn't the issue, but rather the parameter `User *User`. That's the variable you need to rename.

Comment: But it looks like this works, thanks. Yes, this was the only error, everything else works fine.

Comment: @WillWill56 Please accept my answer if your question has been answered with it. Thank you very much. And you're welcome :)

Comment: I tried to accept it, but I have to wait 3 minutes or something, I only just signed up :P (31 seconds to go)

Comment: Also, wow, that was fast. Now I know to be careful when playing with verbose types and variable names.

Comment: @WillWill56 Yeah, StackOverflow has insane response times...if you ask a good question that is. I'm surprised that you didn't get more answers on this actually.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium What did you expect in 6 minutes? And your answer is very good so no need to post an alternative one. :-)